# Text within curly braces (mathjax).

Tags: support, mathjax

Hi: I was defining a set with curly braces and put some words in between. For instance: {f: for all x, f < x}. If I enclose all between dollar signs (ds) the text will be poorly legible. Let's leave the ds's and place one immediately preceding the text and another immediately following. Then I get "unbalanced braces". I just don't know how to use mathjax to write an expression as in the example above. Unless latex has a way to include text within ds's. Can you help me? Anyways, why has mathjax to complain about an unbalanced brace? Can't he leave it as is?

Comment: Try using \text{}.

Comment: Your "unbalanced braces" are probably due to having put only one in each of the two MathJax expressions.   The curly brace is a signifier of *scope* in $\LaTeX$, so you get an error when they are unmatched.  To get the *literal* curly brace character within a MathJax expression, you will need to "escape" them, `\{` and `\}`.  See the [MathJax Basic Tutorial and  Quick Reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), Item 6 on Parentheses.

Answer (score 6):

As hinted at in a comment you can write

`$\{f:  \text{ for all } x, f < x\}$`

$\{f:  \text{ for all } x, f < x\}$

Comment: Else: `$\{f: \forall x, f< x\}$` which renders $\{ f: \forall x, f< x\}$

Comment: Yes, that it is a neat workaround for not being able to write text, avoid text.

Comment: Also stf91, pay close attention to quid's formatting: For any brace (curly bracket) to render in mathjax, you need immediately precede them with a backslash, with no space in between the backslash and the curly bracket. `${x}$` renders as: ${x}$, but `$\{ x \}$` renders as $\{x\}$.

Comment: Similarly, to format $\$$ or $\%$ in mathjax, one needs to precede those symbols with a backslash.  So if you want to format say "After a discount of $40\%$, an item originally priced at $\$50$ will only cost you $\$30$."  You'd format including `$40\%$`, `$\$50$`, and `$\$30$`.